# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: sockets, jsch

I understand that there is duplicate >>> copied from the duplicate >>>As long as your local machine has an SSH server running <<<<< but i cannot comment and cannot as from the question (and im not providing an answer....)

It stated that "As long as your local machine has an SSH server running" but I do not know how to have a SSh server running. I turn on my putty (double click on it) (not sure if this means the SSH(?Putty?) server (?) is running... doubt so...

im really new to socket programming. i am making use of JSch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to try to connect to a remote server (later stage) 
currently, this is the code i use and im trying to connect to my local computer and execute a command (ls to be exact) to do a test. However, i keep hitting the connection refused. I googled and i noticed that there are some articles that mentions on "having a server listening" but I have no idea what it means. Please view my code as below.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;



class SwingWorkerExample {

    JTextField hostField;
    JTextField userNameField;
    JTextField passwordField;
    JPanel panel;


    public SwingWorkerExample() {
        JPanel p = panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
        hostField = new JTextField(20);
        userNameField = new JTextField(20);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
        JButton testButton = new JButton("connect!");
        testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    testConnectionButtonActionPerformed(ev);
                }
            });
        p.add(new JLabel("host:"));
        //127.0.0.1
        p.add(hostField);
        p.add(new JLabel("user:"));
        //mycomputerusername
        p.add(userNameField);
        p.add(new JLabel("password:"));
        //mycomputerpassword
        p.add(passwordField);
        p.add(testButton);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    private void testConnectionButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker(){

                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        JSch jsch = new JSch();

                        String host = hostField.getText();
                        String username = userNameField.getText();
                        String password = passwordField.getText();

                        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host);
                        session.setPassword(password);
                        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

                        session.setTimeout(20000);
                        System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
                        session.connect();

                        return session;
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }

                public void done(){
                    try {
                        System.out.println(get());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

        sw.execute();

    }


    public static void main(String[] egal) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run() {
            SwingWorkerExample ex = new SwingWorkerExample();
            JFrame f = new JFrame("bla");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setContentPane(ex.getPanel());
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }});
    }

    public void remoteLs() throws JSchException, IOException {
        JSch js = new JSch();
        Session s = js.getSession("kellyseo", "192.168.0.103", 22);
        s.setPassword("S9031808z");
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        s.setConfig(config);
        s.connect();

        Channel c = s.openChannel("exec");
        ChannelExec ce = (ChannelExec) c;

        ce.setCommand("ls -l");
        ce.setErrStream(System.err);

        ce.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ce.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }

        ce.disconnect();
        s.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Exit code: " + ce.getExitStatus());

      }



      public void remoteMkdir() throws JSchException, IOException {
        JSch js = new JSch();
        Session s = js.getSession("myusername", "myremotemachine.mycompany.com", 22);
        s.setPassword("mypassword");
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        s.setConfig(config);
        s.connect();

        Channel c = s.openChannel("exec");
        ChannelExec ce = (ChannelExec) c;

        ce.setCommand("mkdir remotetestdir");
        ce.setErrStream(System.err);

        ce.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ce.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }

        ce.disconnect();
        s.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Exit code: " + ce.getExitStatus());

      }

      public void remoteCopy() throws JSchException, IOException, SftpException {
        JSch js = new JSch();
        Session s = js.getSession("myusername", "myremotemachine.mycompany.com", 22);
        s.setPassword("mypassword");
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        s.setConfig(config);
        s.connect();

        Channel c = s.openChannel("sftp");
        ChannelSftp ce = (ChannelSftp) c;

        ce.connect();

        ce.put("/home/myuser/test.txt","test.txt");

        ce.disconnect();
        s.disconnect();    
      }
}
```

BTW i uses commandprompt to ping 127.0.0.1 is okay but if i use telnet 127.0.0.1 it says Could not open connection to the host (I turned on putty(?double click?) , on port 23: Connect failed.
and, SSH = PUTTY ... right? (i cannot use the 'ssh' command in command prompt)

Links:
1) http://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/mailman/message/31745775/

and 2) http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2013/02/java-net-ConnectException-Connection-refused.html

and 3) http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/
 and 4) [Run a command over SSH with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405885/any-good-jsch-examples)
 and 5) [Can we use JSch for SSH key-based communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932005/can-we-use-jsch-for-ssh-key-based-communication)

and... thanks is advance!!

oh, and theres also http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/   (an alternative to JSch.. any advise welcomed!) but when i try to run the example, it says no main. which.. i duno >.< Will stick w JSch till then....

BTW, i try https://serverfault.com/questions/185153/free-public-ssh-server-for-testing-purposes for server but... i have no idea whats the address, username and password. (i also have a http://sdf.org account *newly created* but when i try to connect to it, it says unknownhost. fyi!)

forgot to mention, im using windows 7 and 'yum' is not a command in my command prompt...

Comment: You need to install an SSH server. Putty only acts as your SSH client.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're attempting to connect to your local host via the SSH protocol. With JSCH this isn't exactly socket programming, but your issue is related to socket programming.

Essentially your issue is that your program is trying to connect to a port which isn't open, specifically in this instance it's port 22. You don't have an SSH server so your SSH client can't do anything. You're making a telephone call to someone who doesn't have a phone.

To resolve this issue you need to either find a test server which does have ssh running on it to do your development against or install an ssh server on your local PC. For a windows box your best bet is [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which will allow you to emulate a posix system and run SSHD on your local machine. A google search for cygwin and sshd will provide you with examples of how to set this up.

Comment: Hi, im currently trying using freesshd via http://www.techmalaya.com/2009/08/05/setup-ssh-server-for-windows-freesshd/ and http://osskb.blogspot.sg/2013/10/how-to-resolve-you-dont-have.html for admin rights issue. thanks a lot! and i can PUTTY to my localhost 127.0.0.1 but when i trys to login (via the application GUI , it says ee: com.jcraft.jrexec.JRexecException: JRexec: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect (I created an account via freesshd user1 pwd user1 and checked all access)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but after i can putty to my own localhost, although the above (Sample code, and Thank you for providing the code) i faces the error but the following code (Again, thank you for providing the code. This code is from JCraft, if im not confused, works! i managed to send the command 'help'). Lots of thanks to #chris midolo for providing an answer and #Robby Cornelissen for commenting... although i become more confused (So... SSH means a Server and a Client(?) Sigh... and i though remote access means as long as my computer is on, i can access it from else where... So my computer, in order to be accessed from elsewhere, must also have some kind of server running... OMG! my head hurts....)

Please note that apart from 'help' using other command will result in 'Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process. As per http://www.freesshd.com/index.php?ctt=forum&action=view&topic=1186152755, you need to use **`cmd /c dir`**
and to execute my bat file, i need to use C:\Users\kellyseo\sampling.bat (If i just uses sampling.bat, it shows an error)

My Batch File content is as follows:

```
ECHO RUNNING kellyseo SAMPLING.BAT
@ECHO OFF
CD C:\Users\kellyseo\Desktop
set ldt=kellyseo folder version executed on %date% %time%
echo %ldt%>> logs.txt
EXIT
```

I actually have 2 version of the same file (one i put at desktop) then i can use just 'sampling.bat'

If you do not like to many prompts, apart from removing the prompts, you might also need the following code if you faces this **com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey** (Thanks to [com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003419/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-unknownhostkey))

```
session.setPassword(password);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

**NOTE: #1 prompt = enter password. #2 prompt = enter command. username is 'user1'

```
/* -*-mode:java; c-basic-offset:2; indent-tabs-mode:nil -*- */
/**
 * This program will demonstrate remote exec.
 *   $ CLASSPATH=.:../build javac Exec.java 
 *   $ CLASSPATH=.:../build java Exec
 * You will be asked username, hostname, displayname, passwd and command.
 * If everything works fine, given command will be invoked 
 * on the remote side and outputs will be printed out.
 *
 */
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Exec{
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();  
/*
      String host=null;
      if(arg.length>0){
        host=arg[0];
      }
      else{
        host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                         System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                         "@localhost"); 
      }
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
      host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);
*/
      String user1 = "user1";
      String host1 = "127.0.0.1";
      Session session=jsch.getSession(user1, host1, 22);

      /*
      String xhost="127.0.0.1";
      int xport=0;
      String display=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter display name", 
                                                 xhost+":"+xport);
      xhost=display.substring(0, display.indexOf(':'));
      xport=Integer.parseInt(display.substring(display.indexOf(':')+1));
      session.setX11Host(xhost);
      session.setX11Port(xport+6000);
      */

      // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
      UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();

      String command=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter command", 
                                                 "set|grep SSH");

      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

      // X Forwarding
      // channel.setXForwarding(true);

      //channel.setInputStream(System.in);
      channel.setInputStream(null);

      //channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

      //FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("/tmp/stderr");
      //((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(fos);
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();

      byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
      while(true){
        while(in.available()>0){
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          if(i<0)break;
          System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
          if(in.available()>0) continue; 
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
      }
      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
      Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
      int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
             str,
             "Warning", 
             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
             JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
             null, options, options[0]);
       return foo==0;
    }

    String passwd;
    JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(20);

    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){
      Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
      int result=
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                                      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        passwd=passwordField.getText();
        return true;
      }
      else{ 
        return false; 
      }
    }
    public void showMessage(String message){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
    final GridBagConstraints gbc = 
      new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                             GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                             GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                             new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
    private Container panel;
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
      gbc.gridy++;

      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

      JTextField[] texts=new JTextField[prompt.length];
      for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        if(echo[i]){
          texts[i]=new JTextField(20);
        }
        else{
          texts[i]=new JPasswordField(20);
        }
        panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
      }

      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                                       destination+": "+name,
                                       JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
         ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
        for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
          response[i]=texts[i].getText();
        }
    return response;
      }
      else{
        return null;  // cancel
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac there is a possibility that you haven't allowed remote logins to the server(in this case your machine). Go to System preferences-> Sharing and enable remote login. Also add the user that you want to work with.