# In my Java SFTP class, why am I getting this java.net.ConnectException?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using a Java SFTP library Called JSch , and here is my code :

```
package client;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;

public class SFTPCode_2 {
    public SFTPCode_2() {
        super();
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
     SFTPCode_2 fileTransfer = new SFTPCode_2();              


       try {

           JSch jsch = new JSch();

           String host = "127.0.0.1";
           int port = 22;

           String user = "username";

           Session sessionRead = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
           sessionRead.connect();

           Session sessionWrite = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
           sessionWrite.connect();

           ChannelSftp channelRead = (ChannelSftp)sessionRead.openChannel("sftp");
           channelRead.connect();

           ChannelSftp channelWrite = (ChannelSftp)sessionWrite.openChannel("sftp");
           channelWrite.connect();

           PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream(2048);
           PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);

        /*  channelRead.rename("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Work/ConnectOne_Bancorp/Java_Work/SFTP_1/house.bmp",
                              "C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Work/ConnectOne_Bancorp/Java_Work/SFTP_2/house.bmp"); */


           channelRead.get("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Work/ConnectOne_Bancorp/Java_Work/SFTP_1/house.bmp", pout);
           channelWrite.put(pin , "C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Work/ConnectOne_Bancorp/Java_Work/SFTP_2/house.bmp"); 


           channelRead.disconnect();
           channelWrite.disconnect();

           sessionRead.disconnect();
           sessionWrite.disconnect();




       } catch( JSchException e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); }
         catch (SftpException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) { 
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to copy a file from one directory (within my local machine) to another, using the JSch library .

But it give me this error :

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at client.SFTPCode_2.main(SFTPCode_2.java:43)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
    ... 3 more
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

I tried adding Cygwin ( [from link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241952/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-co#) ) but it still didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a SSH server running on your local machine?

Comment: @roymustang86 - No, I was trying to do this with Cygwin but i'm not sure how. Is there a special command to run in Cygwin to get it up?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC281 This has a detailed step by step way of configuring ssh and starting the sshd in cygwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what line is throwing the exception. Try to surround each Jsch action with try/catch, like so:

```
        Session sessionRead = null;
        try {
            sessionRead = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            System.out.println("Issue getting session.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            sessionRead.connect(); // do you need to set properties first?
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            System.out.println("Issue connecting to session.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For me, when I use Jsch, I had to add session properties to make the connection eg, on sessionRead.connect() .

```
        sessionRead.setPassword("password");
        sessionRead.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sessionRead.connect();
```