# JSch how to use with PuTTY private key

Tags: putty, jsch, private-key, public-key

I'm trying to use JSch with a private key configuration. I've generated a public and private key using PuTTYgen but am unsure what to do with both of the files.

Which key (public/private) needs transferring to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First, you need to register your PuTTYgen-generated **public** key on the server. See [Getting ready for public key authentication](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-gettingready) or (my) [Set up SSH public key authentication](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key).
- And finally see [Can we use JSch for SSH key-based communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4932005/850848) for details on using the **private** key in JSch.

---

Make sure you use the latest version of JSch, as older versions do not support the .ppk format natively.

Comment: Perfect answer. Have now successfully connected using keypair access.

Answer (score 5):

Code Snippet for connection using PuTTy private Key (.ppk)

```
JSch jsch=new JSch();
jsch.setKnownHosts("~\.ssh\know_hosts");
jsch.addIdentity("~\sshkey.ppk");
Session session=jsch.getSession("ec2-user", "54.12.11.90", 22);
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.connect();
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
channel.connect(3*1000);
```

Have used 0.1.54 version of Jsch

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please do not suggest anyone to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` without explaining security consequences. You are losing a protection against [MIMT attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so!