# Java JSchException: Auth cancel

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am currently seeing this issue when attempting to ssh into a box from using JSch. I have tested the connection using Cygwin and it connects seamlessly. I have generated the keypair and placed the Public key in `authorized_keys` file on the remote server.

Below is an extract from the logs

```
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
INFO: Next authentication method: password
INFO: Disconnecting from xx.xx.xx.xx port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
```

Code used to established connection

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("cipher",",aes256-cbc");
config.put("mac.c2s", "hmac-sha2-256");
config.put("KEXs", "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256");
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
Session session = jsch.getSession(username,host,port);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.setConfig(config);
session.getPort();
session.connect();
session.setPortForwardingL(tunnelLocalPort,tunnelRemoteHost,tunnelRemotePort);
```

Here is the code for the UserInfo ui

```
String password = null;

@Override
public String getPassphrase() {
    return null;
}
@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String passwd) {
    password = passwd;
}

@Override
public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that you're using to call jsch to make this connection? If you're using a key file, what is the name of the key file?

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to SSH I believe the key I'm using is id_rsa

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but still important: don't ever hard code any password strings into your production binary.

Comment: So do you want to use password or public key authentication?

Comment: Public key authentication is what I'm going for

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jsch isn't trying to use a key file, because your code doesn't tell jsch what key file to use. You need to call `Jsch.addIdentity()` to add one or more key files to the session:

```
jsch.addIdentity("C:\users\jdoe\.ssh\id_rsa");
```

or

```
String passphrase = ...;
jsch.addIdentity("C:\users\jdoe\.ssh\id_rsa",
                 passphrase.getBytes());
```

There are other varieties of the `addIdentity()` function, if you want to supply the information in some other format.

Comment: I have added this to the code and it points to the corresponding key but I still have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The "Auth cancel" is thrown when the authentication implementation throws `JSchAuthCancelException`. What in turn usually happens when the `UserInfo` implementation return false from one of its methods.

*Your code does not show what is the `ui`. So I cannot provide more information until you show us more code.*

---

Also you write about key pair, yet your code does not show any use of a key. You instead set a password.

For private key authentication with JSch see for example:
[Can we use JSch for SSH key-based communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4932005/850848)