# SSH Client - how to?

Tags: android, ssh, composer-php, laravel-artisan

i'm trying to setup SSH Client on my android phone (HTC) to connect and manage my laravel application via command line, running artisan commands and composer on the run.

i successfully did this using putty on my laptop computer, but i cant seem to find one suitable for android - that accepts private keys, e.g .ppk files.

please is there any better alternative that can do this, or if anyone has achieved this i'd be glad if you let me in.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried jsch?

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

it has support for private keys

Comment: i havent tried.. i need support from someone that has tried and has gotten this working. thanks.

Comment: and Jsch has no android support? looks like a desktop utility.

Comment: its just a regular java jar
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar/0.1.54/jsch-0.1.54.jar/download

just download it and import it into your android studio project

Comment: for an example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932005/can-we-use-jsch-for-ssh-key-based-communication