# SFTP with java client when keys are shared

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, ssh-keys

I have two servers A and B.
I want to SFTP a file from server A to B.

Public key of server A (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) has been added to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of server B.

From command line, I can SFTP from server A to B without entering password.
However, from a `Java` client using library [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) I am unable to make SFTP connection to server B and I am getting authentication error:

```
Error occurred during SFTP. Auth fail
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Is there a way I can connect to server B for SFTP purposes using `Java` client without specifying password?

Below is my `Java` code for reference:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;

        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("processor", "remoteserver.myorg.com", 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            System.out.println("Trying to connect...");
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected successfully.");

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            System.out.println("Doing SFTP...");
            sftpChannel.put("/tmp/test.txt", "/some/remote/folder");
            System.out.println("Success");
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();

        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred during SFTP. " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addIdentity()` api in `jsync` and point to your private key file location.

Ref: 
[Can we use JSch for SSH key-based communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932005/can-we-use-jsch-for-ssh-key-based-communication)

```
   String privateKey = "~/.ssh/id_rsa";    
   jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
   System.out.println("identity added ");    
   Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
   System.out.println("session created.");
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions. Vote them to be closed as duplicate instead.